# Warnings in nav-menu when visiting query pages

Tags: wp-query, menus

Using [query-wrangler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-wrangler/), similar to drupal's views, I created some query pages.
When I visit these pages, in the top-navigation-menu there is this warning:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /.../wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 425
```

The line cited by the warning is inside the ancestral post object wich I fully report here:

```
// ancestral post object
(
    'post_type' == $parent_item->type &&
    ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
    is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $queried_object->ancestors ) &&
    $parent_item->object != $queried_object->ID
) ||
```

Line 425 is the one starting with `in_array(`
The top-navigation-menu items are not related with the query pages. Are simple pages, some of them childpages.
I really don't know how to fix this warning, because I don't understand to what is related.

Comment: It seems that `$queried_object->ancestors` is returning `NULL`. Maybe just check this statement before, and if it IS returning `NULL` don't use it as second arguemnt in `in_array` but use `array()`.

Comment: The problem is that the plugin is doing something very wrong. I don't know how it works, but checking "something" somewhere, where it isn't supposed to exist, shows a lack of design and concept. Maybe better change the plugin. **But:** Did you tell the developer in the official support form about it?

Comment: Hi tf and @kaiser.
There is a report in the support forum [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-when-link-to-query-page-is-placed-in-menu) that describe a similar issue. Actually I don't understand wich part of code of query-wrangler plugin produce this situation. A sort of workaround could be to hide the warning because everything else work in the menu. But it's not a good practice (I'll lose also other warnings).
_Sorry for duplicated comment_

Comment: @Kropot You can any time delete a comment. Hover over it, tick the small `x`.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks :) Actually, it seems that the developer is no longer supporting the plugin. His last reply is dated two months ago.

Comment: How does "dated two month ago" lead you to "not longer supported"? Sometimes I haven't got enough free time to deliver (free) support for my plugins. And considering that it's only two month, I'd just leave a report there anyway. It's important for the developer, other users and a developer who might want to take over development in case.

Comment: Well, **support is a privilege**, not a right :) From the plugin page: _Last Updated: 2013-1-5_, so I'd say file a bug report and wait until he got time...

Comment: @kaiser I apologize for my bad english. I mean "Actually" = "at the moment". No answers from the developer. Besides that, some people are trying to contribute to the plugin adding how-to and tutorials. Personally I managed how to add the "category" field in the "fields" of a query, but I don't know how to contribute to the module (publishing the edited files in the support forum?)
I think that this plugin would be a great solution for managing queries with an UI. It's worth support this module, also to opposite other paid solutions. But actually it's a bit bugged. :(

Comment: You can still fix it and make a fork, then upload it to the repo and share it.